# Left Join , Select Record

Tags: sql, sql-server

есть две Table, хочу сделать LEFT JOIN так чтобы с LeftTable вынести все записи , а с RightTable только те записи в котором IsActive = 1,

без использование WHERE

```
CREATE TABLE LeftTable (
   ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
   FirstName nvarchar(MAX) NOT NULL,
   LastName nvarchar(MAX) NOT NULL,
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE RightTable (
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    IsActive bit,
    LeftTableID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES LeftTable(ID)
);
```

Comment: По каким полям join?

Comment: ID и LeftTableID

Comment: А почему вам нельзя использовать `where`? Как раз хорошая ситуация для этого. Вообще же можно в `on` условие засунуть, если уж так хочется (с `and`, разумеется)

Comment: Условие ```id=lefttableid and isactive=1```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM LeftTable 
LEFT OUTER JOIN RightTable ON LeftTable.ID = RightTable.LeftTableID
                          AND RightTable.IsActive = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Это кажется очень тривиальным.

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.LeftTable AS l LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT * FROM FROM righTable
    WHERE Isactive = 1
) AS r
ON l.ID = r.LeftTableID;
```

Comment: *Это кажется очень тривиальным.* Ага... и именно поэтому Вы дали НЕПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ ответ?

Comment: @Akina. Без реальных данных не просто проверить SQL.

Comment: Создайте тестовые данные и проверте. Какие сложности?

Comment: @0xdb. Это ответственность оригинального постера.

Comment: Тут не нужно ничего проверять, не нужны никакие данные. Условие по полю правой таблицы, отличное от проверки на NULL, во WHERE - немедленно и однозначно преобразует LEFT JOIN в INNER JOIN. Это аксиома. Впрочем, Вы уже исправили ошибочный запрос.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Давая ответ, вы перенимаете эту ответственность.